# Using Solar Charge Controller with AC Power instead of Panels

Tags: batteries, solar-cell, charge, controller

I'm working on a project here which needs to have a small SLA backup battery.

I have a cheap PWM solar charge controller already and I want to use plugged into an AC power supply (48V DC out) in place of solar panels.

I've tested it on my bench and it works but is there anything I should be worried about long-term with this setup?

Edit: Here is the datasheet - [Tycon Syetems model TP-SC24-20](https://tyconsystems.com/documentation/Spec%20Sheets/TP-SC24-20%20Charge%20Controller%20Spec%20Sheet.pdf)

[image]

Comment: "cheap" might be an important word there: A solar panel is neither a constant voltage nor a constant current supply. The better class of solar charge controllers attempt to adjust the operating point on the panel's I-V curve to maximize the product of I*V (power). That operating point changes as the flux of incident light on the panel changes. (Google for "Maximum Power Point Tracking"). I don't know what an MPPT charge controller would do when hooked up to a constant voltage supply.

Comment: Can you describe what you have with specs, links or a datasheet?

Comment: Yes, "cheap" and "long-term" are incompatible.  When you're ready to get serious, get a Morningstar. MS literature specifically says you can drive it from a DC power supply within limits.  (mainly you must limit current, since solar panels are current limited).

Comment: You need to tell us as much as possible. PV panel ratings (at least Vmp. Imp), Battery voltage and Ah capacity. Controller brand and model. Any links and model names and specs and ... . || What is the battery voltage? "Small SLA backup" usually translates as 12V or 6V. If so then operating from a 48V supply is "not a good idea". A solar panel is a constanmtish current source and if a 48V nominal PV panel is connected to a 12V battery it acts as a current source at about Isc max charge and IF the controller expects a 12V battery it will stop charging when ~= appropriate.  ...

Comment: ... Whereas a mains 48V supply  will not appreciate being "shorted" by a 12V battery. | A cheap controller may be PWM but is unlikely to be MPPT. At best it will PWM 84V to 12V to TRY to limit current. Succe3ss uncertain - unless they have a low padd filter set to below PWM rate you get hard shorts to 12V and then OC breaks. Tell us more!

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 here's the datasheet https://tyconsystems.com/documentation/Spec%20Sheets/TP-SC24-20%20Charge%20Controller%20Spec%20Sheet.pdf

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Do you know roughly what the current must be limited to?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon No solar panels will be connected. Battery Voltage is 12V, 7Ah. Spec sheet is above in comment. The charge controller supports panels up to 55V so I should be under that limit. It's definitely a PWM controller. Is there any other information needed that can help?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Which Moringstar product specifies it can be driven from a DC power supply?

Comment: @fullyjosh Morningstar Sunguard is where I saw it.  That's their cheapie. The current limit is stated in the documentation and roughly matches the unit's solar rating.

Comment: That controller says 35Vin ABSOLUTE MAXIMUM .  If it "works on yiur bench" Murphy is just leading you into a grap. || It MAY be that the battery is loading it down enough to save you. | Q1. Have you charged the battery to the fully charged state (when Vin will become unloaded)  || It makes no sense to use a 35V (or 48V ) psu in this application. About 16V should be enough, if that. = 14.6V equalise charge and a little more for controller drop.  You are effectively just making a battery charger. A battery charger (close to free at yard sales) would probably do as well or better. || ...

Comment: ... Q2. What is the current rating of your PSU? - it's not obvious that the controller knows its a 7Ah battery -  IF you used a high current PSU it would probably drive your battery to an early death, || Put all you know in your question both initially and as you provide more data. That way you get best answers and do not waste your own time or other people's.

Comment: To create link references use Ctrl-L - You can provide visible text and a link. Easy and works well. OR do what I did manually - look at your markdown code to see.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Q1) sorry I was going off of the Solar Panel Voltage. I assumed "Rated Voltage" was for the battery / load. Regardless, I'm not against using a lower Voltage PSU. 

Q2) My 48V power supply has a rating of 2A which is well below the 20A rating of the controller and at the rating of my battery which is 2A. Again, not against getting a PSU with a lower output current.

Thanks for the link advice

Comment: @fullyjosh You want a lower psu VOLTAGE more closely rated to battery VOLTAGE. A psu CURRENT that is as high as the battery will tolerate will maximise charge rate. Lower is OK but slower. When charging a q2V battery the controller will have a mimimum Vin (usually panel but now psu). This is hopefully about 16V (as I noted above) but MAY be higher. With a PWM controller any Vin geater than Vbattery is wasted. That's life. | Looking at that brief datasheet I'd expect 16V would be fine - asking Tycon is easy and should confirm this.

Comment: What brand & model is your battery. There should be a specsheet giving max charge current. This depends on whether you use it in float mode (usually not loaded, loaded occasionally) or depper discharge mode where you cycle it regularly.